# Comparing Heatmaps over time

Tags: spatial-statistics, density, comparison, spatial-cluster

We have a huge dataset of mobile users (tourists) and want to see how the density in a city has changed (from one spot to another) before during Covid. Of course we can create a heatmap for different timeframes and compare visually, but we want to statistically compare changes. We all have no GIS background. Any suggestions?

Comment: One approach would be to fit a linear trend line at each pixel location over the time series. Your map will show the slope of the line at each pixel. Here is an approach using Earth Engine: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_regression